# Ford F150 XL - is there a hack for the radio?

Tags: ford, f-150, trim, factory-flaws

I just purchased a 2018 Ford F150 XL crew cab.

The radio is driving me insane.

For example

I can't play another directory of MP3s - while driving.  For an 1 1/2 commute this is aggravating.

I have to reach over to pick AM or FM.

Every time I select MP3 it is in pause mode.

The music navigation is annoying.

Is there an update (or hack aka MagicLantern for Canon) to make this better?